Creating a shader for a non-directional metal material
I'm creating renderings of the products we sell for our website. All of our finishes are non-directional, meaning we use a circular palm sander on the metal. So it is essentially brushed but in a randomized, radial movement. I am new to blender but it would be very helpful if I could create these materials. The photos below are what I am shooting for. I'd love for the renderings to be as realistic as possible.


here is what I have come up with so far. Any tips for me to get it closer to yours?


A metallic material with low roughness will get you there. What is your question exactly ?

I guess I'm just so new to blender that I could use a little direction with that. I've been playing around with it but it still looks a little too much like a rendering in my opinion.

You'll need to add some textures to control the reflectivity of the metal, which can be found online for free. This one from this site is pretty decent. There's also textures.com and other places to find them. You'll want to add some to the roughness input on your material as well as maybe fiddling with the Anisotropy (the "brushed" look). Using an HDRI to light your scene will also help contribute to realism as well.

It seems to me you might be in a position of making yourself some higher quality reference material than you can easily find online. Is it possible for you to take some high quality, high resolution photographs of the material finish? Preferably some in a more complex natural environment and some with even color reflections from different angles as well as larger area or the material so low frequency patterns can also be visible.

Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question. To add details to your question, simply [edit] your question instead of using the answer section.

Calling those finishes "non-directional" may be an internal/marketing term you use, but IMO it's not physically accurate. The circular brush is making many anisotropic swirls. They are all directional, they just change direction such that the overall surface has no uniform direction.

As far as I can tell the realism of the material is in the texture of roughness and possibly other properties like variation in reflected color(although it's hard to tell without observing the material in real life).
I can get a bit closer to the look just by using some sort of noise:

However, as you can clearly see, it's not close to photorealism, because my quick procedural texture is not close to the one the actual material has. The variation in roughness has complex organic patterns that I cannot even see from the reference to be able to attempt to make it realistically procedurally(which is probably not very straight forward even with better reference). My belief is that if you want a good result, you need to recreate that texture with complex noise that has subtle and specific variation in detail, shapes and scratches. I think the best approach would be to experiment with a large sheet of metal with that exact finish and see what uniform single color background it could reflect in a way so that the texture is visible, photograph it and extract the texture from the photos. If that is not possible, more reference would still be needed and it might be possible to achieve better results by attempting to make the texture in image editing software like Photoshop, Gimp or Krita. You would need to observe and identify various kinds of noise patterns to do so. Frequency separation techniques might be helpful there. I think that would require a lot of experimentation and effort either way.
Oh, and I assume you would model the product to exact dimensions - I think I got the slopes of the bottom completely wrong, they are probably more shallow.

The patterns might be in part related to corrosion, so you might look into other metals like copper where they are way more clearly visible. They might be similar in texture but differ in color and contrast only.

Thanks Martynas, This is much more realistic than what I have been able to come up with. I copied your nodes and my version looks a lot different. I realize a lot of that can depend on lighting and scale and what not. What kind of lighting do you have and what type of background?

It's some HDRI from HDRI Haven. It is important for the look - you are right, because most of what you see in metal material like this is reflections, so you need something to reflect.

Is there a way I can upload a photo on here so I can show you what I have and get some feedback of what I need to do? Do I need to answer my own question so I can add a pic?

If you have an answer to your own question it's considered to be a very nice practice to post it as an answer here even if it's your own question. Then the solution you ended up with will remain for others who might be searching for an answer to a similar question in the future.

i use sharex, but theres other software. you take a photo of what you want to share, then it makes a url for you to post. the comments allow you to create links to images.
Info Link

also, anisotropy is an essential setting for some metals where the specular gets smeared. gets really cool when you plug some scratch textures into it. though might not be applicable here. link

have you tried the anisotropic property? 
You can use a texture map to fine control rotation.
Example of a random scratch texture controlling anisotropic rotation.


Anisotropic reflection is clearly visible in your shared image, but it's not visible at all in the images shared by OP. Why would they try something that does not apply to the situation?..

So one thing that might be worth noting is that when I import my stl file I scale it down to .12 in order for it to fit under the camera properly. Would this be affecting my outcome of materials?

Another question, @martynas, How did you get those cross brakes in the basin. I assume it was something to do with altering the mesh, but that looks nice and my drawings didn't have those.

@MartynasŽiemys his material could very well take advantage of anisotropic for realism, just not to the degree that im using it in my photos. ive got very similar results to his using a bit of anistropic + microscratches

@ColinHildenbrand if your referring to my photos of the metal, its just the anisotropic setting in the material. then i added a black and white scratch texture to randomize the anistropic rotation.

Sorry John, I was referring to @MartynasŽiemys on how he made the cross brake lines on the bottom of the sink basin. I would like to do those on my file.

@JohnCheathem, well, if one observes any on their reference, they should use it. There might be some on the material - it's not visible in this case. Anisotropic shader is not for scratches though and your renders look nothing like the reference in the question so in this case, it should not be used and this answer may be confusing. It's good idea to get better reference(for the millionths time! @ColinHildenbrand) and look closer if some anisotropy might be there.  Cross indentations at the bottom are in the geometry of the model. Play with HDRI rotation to see what gives nicer reflections.

IMO, buffing any metal with a circular palm sander, unless it's using the very softest cloth, is going to cause anisotropic regions. It seems to me that OP's photos definitely do show this, variations in anisotropic reflection angle causing a non-uniform appearance.
